# Is Edward Cullen a pedophile?

Tags: twilight

Since Edward Cullen is over 100 years old when he first meets Bella, would he technically be considered a pedophile because he is attracted to underage girls? Bella is, after all, considered a minor by the state of Washington. Has a vampire ever been arrested for this?

Comment: See, this is thinking too hard into something that does not deserve this much thought. Can you be considered a pedophile if you cannot even be considered living? Do or can such laws even apply to the unliving? Now you've got me doing it...

Comment: Voted to close as not constructive.  Seems a natural topic for chat, though.

Comment: I agree with **Kyle Jones** -- Fine topic for chat, but a tad salacious and gratuitous for the site. VTC Non Constructive

Answer (score 23):

**Edward Cullen is over 100 years old**

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedophilia):

> As a medical diagnosis, pedophilia, or paedophilia, is defined as a psychiatric disorder in persons who are 16 years of age or older typically characterized by a primary or exclusive sexual interest in prepubescent children

So, he meets the age requirement for himself, but not the sexual interest in prepubescent children.

**would he technically be considered a pedophile because he is attracted to underage girls?**

Bella is 17 when she meets Edward - a minor in that she is under 18. But the age of consent in Washington [is only 16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_consent_in_North_America#Washington), so she is old enough to consent under state laws.

So, by definition and according to local laws, Edward Cullen is NOT a pedophile - nor would he be arrested for having sex with Bella.

Comment: Let's keep it real though, what does a man who is a hundred years old find he has in common with a seventeen year old? When I have tried dating women much younger than myself (a decade or so) I find we just don't share enough in common to sustain a relationship. I have always found the relationship to be a bit unrealistic at best. If she were 40 years old, I could see it, but at 17 she has no idea of the world at all...

Comment: Even if she was under the age of consent though, and by correct standards he's not considered a paedophile. Further down that wiki-link: "Nepiophilia (Infantophilia) is used to refer to a sexual preference for infants and toddlers (usually ages 0–3),[31] pedophilia is used for individuals with a primary sexual interest in prepubescent children aged 13 or younger,[1] and hebephilia is defined as individuals with a primary sexual interest in 11-14 year old pubescents"

Comment: Quite obviously he loves her for her mind. The amazing insights that only 17 yr old girls are capable of, the incredible wisdom that comes from having lived so little but so completely. I hate to sound like a romantic, I'm just telling it like it is.

Comment: @JohnO *"from having lived so little but so completely"* You clearly haven't read the books. Bella is described in very little detail, but nothing indicates she's the type who would "live so completely"

Comment: @RoyalFlush I think John dropped his `</sarcasm>` tag

Comment: @Thaddeus - I'm familiar with a great deal of 40 year old men and women who know less about the world than I did at 17. For a more extreme example, Alexander the Great led armies at around that age. Tais of Athens was already a well known hetera (sp) at that age (known for her brains, BTW). Mind you, I hate defending Twilight :)

Comment: I am not saying you could not find an extraordinary individual who COULD be interesting. But the character Bella was in no way as awesome or interesting as Alexander the Great. If she was, that would have at least made the interest understandable and perhaps a bit less icky-feeling...

Comment: @JohnO Actually, that could be reasonable:  It looks like he was turned in his teens; perhaps he's mentally stunted at that age as well?

Comment: There is a lot of fiction that deals with people in "loops" or simply "frozen". The general consensus is that personality is less how old your body is and more how old your mind is. Edward's lived 100 years, despite his body being frozen at 17; that's a lot of living. In fact it could be argued that that's why he's stayed single so long; it's hard to find an "old soul" in a 17-year-old body.

Comment: Also, look at Groundhog Day. Bill Murray doesn't physically age, yet he is very different by the end of his loop.